# Which is correct: Betty and he are friends or Betty and him are friends? Please explain. Thank you

Tags: pronouns, subjects, proper-nouns, personal-pronouns, direct-objects

Isn't it him is an object pronoun and not subject pronoun. Why do we need to use Betty and him and not Betty and he? Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You use him as an object of a preposition or a verb, so

> 'He and Betty are friends' is correct.
>
> 'Betty and him are friends' is wrong.
>
> 'Betty is friends with him' is also correct.